# Reading binary file with a known sequence of datatypes

Tags: matlab, binary

I am trying to read a binary file that has 4 header lines and the rest are data. The data is of the form abcd, where abc are 3 values having double precision and d is an unsigned short (no spaces between the numbers or the sets of numbers). Below is the code that I tried and the resultant 'data1' has no data in it. Any suggestions?

```
filename1 = 'myfile.bin';
fid = fopen(filename1, 'r');
for k = 1 : 4 %ignore the first 4 lines
    fgetl(fid); 
end   
data1 = fscanf(fid,'%f%f%f%ushort',Inf); 
fclose(fid)
```

Comment: how is the data separated? spaces? please give an example

Comment: No spaces between the data.. seems like abcdabcdabcd...

Comment: then how are you supposed to know where to separate it? Provide a numeric example!